# Firebase: Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSecondsNonbillable'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase cloud function, it was execute fine but no am getting "Quota exceeded issue "

**    Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSecondsNonbillable' and limit 'CLIENT_PROJECT-1d' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:0000000'., Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSecondsNonbillable' and limit 'CLIENT_PROJECT-100s' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:0000000'., Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSecondsDailyNonbillable' and limit 'CLIENT_PROJECT-1d' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:0000000'.); to increase quotas, enable billing in your project at **

Comment: You exceeded your free quota for the amount of time you can spend running code in Cloud Functions.  Contact Firebase support for more information.  Stack Overflow will be of no help to you.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: I have an active blaze plan and just received the same error